# Loading from a Null pointer, why doesn't this crash my program?

Tags: null, llvm, llvm-ir

I am having this code here. It seems to be dereferencing a null pointer, yet when I compile and run it, it doesn't crash! There is no segmentation fault being generated here. `@dx.nothing` is defined as `0`. Later the application `load`s a value from that memory location, which is a `i32*`. So it appears that the application is dereferencing a null pointer. However, it doesn't seem to be a problem.

```
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

@dx.nothing = internal constant i32 0

define i32 @main() {
    %1 = load i32, i32* @dx.nothing
    %2 = load i32, i32* @dx.nothing
    %3 = load i32, i32* @dx.nothing
    %4 = fmul fast float 5.000000e-01, 5.000000e-01
    %5 = fmul fast float 0x3FC99999A0000000, 5.000000e-01
    %6 = fmul fast float 0x3FECCCCCC0000000, 5.000000e-01
    %7 = fmul fast float 1.000000e+00, 5.000000e-01
    %8 = load i32, i32* @dx.nothing
    %9 = load i32, i32* @dx.nothing
    %10 = load i32, i32* @dx.nothing

    ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: Is it *guaranteed* to crash, or just enter some UB?

Comment: @user2864740 I was under the impression that dereferencing a null pointer would cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never mind**, I screwed up with this question. I was reading the code wrong.
I figured out that this line is not actually creating a null pointer. It is instead creating a global constant with the value `i32 0`

```
@dx.nothing = internal constant i32 0
```

Then when the application later attempts to load that value, it would load the `i32 0` in.

Consider the following example:

```
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

@stuff1 = internal constant i32 5

define i32 @main() {
    %1 = load i32, i32* @stuff1
    ret i32 %1
}
```

This code creates a global constant with the value `i32 5`, `load`s that value into the virtual register `%1`, and returns that. So the `5` is returned as the exit code from the `@main` function.

If you were to compile and run this example code:

```
$ llvm-as code.ll -o code.bc
$ lli code.bc
$ echo $?
5
```